# Besides disk access, is there performance penalties in running a program from USB drive?

Tags: linux, openwrt, node.js

I would like to run a nodejs server on an openwrt router. Because node is too big to be installed on my router's flash, I need to run it from a USB drive. I know that reading and writing is slower on USB than on the flash, but I am not so familiar with OS workings and I was wondering if this incurs any performance penalty once the program is started and loaded in RAM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no other performance penalty except disk access speed and latency (delay before the first byte is read) in accessing your files.

When accessing a lot of data the system will be busy transporting this data using the USB (b)us and its access to it (e.g. using a I2C-USB bridge).  This data path will use more data and could in theory be saturated.

One more thing you may want to consider is the following. Many USB thumb drives and the like are not made for 24/7 operation.  When in use every hour of the day they may age much more quickly (I had one which died after a few months only).  Your openwrt device may or may not be able to issue sleep commands, but even if it does this may not help very much.